# External Hard Disk's secter could not be read?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, check-disk

I've an 500 GB Seagate External Hard Disk (NTFS) . Currently, I can't open it at Windows. Thus, I've tired with `chkdsk` command .. but still it stopped and can't continue checking disk..

Also I've tired with `fsck` on Mac . Then, it shows me the Error ..

```
/Volumes/<HD Name>/ is not a character device CONTINUE? yes

/Volumes/<HD Name>/ (NO WRITE)

CANNOT READ: BLK 16 CONTINUE? yes

THE FOLLOWING DISK SECTORS COULD NOT BE READ: 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ioctl (GCINFO): Inappropriate ioctl for device fsck: /Volumes/<HD Name>/: 
can't read disk label
```

The volume I've used is around 300 GB , Thus, it's hard to back up and format again .

Thus, any helpful suggestions and solutions will be appreciated pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not identify which Seagate external drive you are using so we do not know how the drive is supposed to be connected or powered.

If it is powered from the USB cable and you are using only one USB port, then it may be underpowered. In that case, you want to use a cable with two USB connectors on them. (An [example](http://www.digistor.com/DIGISTOR-Dual-Cable-for-Slim-External-Drive-Mini-USB-DC) Warning! May not work with your drive).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use fsck on a NTFS filesystem. The linux ntfsprogs might work for you (?). I'd look into those, there's a ntfsfix utility that might do what you want.